# how to disable auto smoothing by default in 2.74

Tags: import

when I import an obj file, by default auto smoothing is enabled. Is it possible to change this option as in the old realises?

Comment: you do you mean _smooth shading_ or the Smooth Groups option in the Obj importer panel?

Comment: I mean the option in object data panel/normal/auto smoothing

Answer (score 4):

You cannot (well, not from UI or other 'user-land' ways). Note however that 'autosmooth' here is a bit of a weak name, since it actually means you are using (custom) normals as defined by the .obj, instead of auto-computed ones by Blender…

Now, if you really want to disable that by default, you'll have to open `addons/io_scene_obj/import.py` in your Blender installation, search for `me.use_auto_smooth = True` (should be around line 657 currently), and replace it by `me.use_auto_smooth = False` (or just comment it by adding a `#` in front of that line).

But again, don’t think you want to do that, at least I do not see why you would…

Comment: I just want have possibility to choose when using smooth or flat mode, depending on the kind of geometry, as in the old realises. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Replace the two files (init and import ) in the `/2.74/scripts/addons/io_scene_obj/` with these [**init**.py](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35739) and [import_obj.py](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35740) restart blender and you'll have the option for auto smooth in the importer settings ( a check box )